# How can I create a set of pixel coordinates for a line in Python?

Tags: python, math, graph

I've got some code that's searching pixel by pixel from a starting point, at a certain angle, until it finds a pixel (a non-white pixel)

It only has to search around 300 pixels: I'm currently using polar to Cartesian function 300 times...

```
def pol2cart(rotdist, cwangle):
    x = rotdist * numpy.cos(cwangle)
    y = rotdist * numpy.sin(cwangle)
    return(x, y)
```

... but it's very slow, up to 68 milliseconds per search (if it goes the whole 300 without finding anything) and I've got quite a lot of these searches to do... which is the main cause of my overall function taking about 20 seconds to run (I'd be happy with <2 seconds)

My theory is: if I can create a list of coordinates that describe a line from the centre point to the 300px distance end point, I only need to run pol2cart once (go get the end point) and then I can just iterate over my "line list"...

So I could do something like (psuedo):

```
If line == UppyDowny:
    for Y in line:
        Solve X 

elseIf line == LeftyRighty:
    for X in line:
        Solve Y 

linecoords.append((X,Y))
```

... I'm not asking for someone to code that for me, but I'm wondering if there's an existing common library function that achieves that? (as it'll no  doubt be faster than how I would code the above and also a lot faster than 600 cos/sin calls)

Comment: Maybe this question should be a duplicate of this one: [get all points of a straight line in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25837544/331117)

Comment: Consider reading about line-drawing algorithms such as Bresenham's.

Comment: Cool, thanks. In expanding the above psuedo code in to Python code i ended up with a "DDA" algorithm... I see Bresenham's faster and more accurate: I'll give that a whirl! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Digging around I found an [Eye Diagram](https://github.com/mpastell/SciPy-CookBook/blob/master/rst/EyeDiagram.rst) which includes a pure Python Bresenham implementation and a Cython one, HTH :)